# Make more than one clicked button change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have 10 red buttons. I want them to change the color to blue  after click and remain blue no matter where I click after that. Right now I use :active and what it does, it only turns the color for the most recently clicked button and goes back to original after I click anything else.

But I want all clicked buttons on my page to turn to a changed color.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('blue');  
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  color:red;
}
  button.blue {
    color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in CSS, you'll need to use a little bit of trickery involving the `transition-delay` property; in the button's normal state, set it to a ridiculously high number and the reset it to `0s` in the button's active state.

```
button{
    background:red;
    transition:background .25s linear 999999s;
}
button:active{
    background:blue;
    transition-delay:0s,
}
```